# Ignite on local file system

Tags: ignite

I'm trying to store data from ignite cache to local file system. While running the code, I'm getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IGFS is not configured:

Can some one help me on this???

Comment: IGFS is a file system for hadoop, do you really want to use it, or you just want to persist data locally, like in DB?

Comment: I want the data to be saved in local File system.

Answer (score 3):

IGFS is an in-memory file system, so sounds like it's not what you're looking for. Take a look at Ignite native persistence storage which should help you to achieve your goals: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store

Comment: I want to take the data from cache to be stored in local filesystem. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @Savitharavikumar You said that want to store file to local file system, but try to store hdfs (hadoop file system). Valentin Kulichenko posted the link to doc which shows how store data to local file system. What do you really want?

Comment: @Savitharavikumar Ignite persistence storage serves exactly this purpose. Please refer to the provided link for details.

Comment: Valentin and Nikolay - I want file in local filesystem. So I had configured in config.xml. When I ran it,i† shows IGFS is not configured. The below is my configuration setup. Should i change anything in that?

Comment: <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="persistentStoreConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.PersistentStoreConfiguration"/>
            </property>
    <property name="fileSystemConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.FileSystemConfiguration">
              
              <property name="name" value="/Users/mobility/Documents/cache.txt" />
              
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

Comment: @Savitharavikumar You don't need IGFS to persist the data. Just add PersistentStoreConfig‌​uration bean.